# Why using a custom function within dplyr::mutate() gives me the wrong result?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two custom functions, `myfun1` and `myfun2`:

```
myfun1 <- function(x){sqrt(x) * 6}

myfun2 <- function(x) {
  set.seed(x)
  logis_simul <- rlogis(100, 40, 10)
  return(mean(logis_simul, na.rm=T))
}
```

When I use `mutate()` with my custom functions, I expect to get the same behavior, but that is not the case:

```
d <- tibble::tibble(x=0:100)

d %>% mutate(Col2 = myfun1(x))  # Works
d %>% mutate(Col2 = myfun2(x))  # Fail! Why is it giving me repeated results?
purrr::map_dbl(d$x, myfun2)     # supposed to be the same as previous line. It's not.
```

Comment: It's because the first is vectorized: try `myfun1(1:10)`, while the second is not: try `myfun2(1:10)`. Try e.g. `myfun2b <- function(x) replicate(length(x), myfun2())` or `myfun2c <- Vectorize(myfun2b)`.

Comment: Maybe because `myfun2` is not related to your input `x`. I don't understand why you are expecting the same output

Comment: @dc37 bad wording. by "same result" meant "same behavior", as in vectorized behavior

Comment: @Dan, I see maybe it will have been interesting to clarify the expected output you were looking for

Comment: @Axeman, Understood. Question remaining is: WHY myfun1 was naturally vectorized and myfun2 not, given the way I wrote them ?

Comment: @Dan `mean()` is a collapsing function. It's not vectorized. Your custom function is only vectorized if all the functions it uses are vectorized.

Comment: @MrFlick, brilliant. That solves it for me: mean is a collapsing function. A function will be vectorized if all of its components are vectorized. mean() is breaking that condition on myfun2. Thanks. I'd like to point to documentation on this topic in an answer if you agree and open the question again. The alternative question has broken links in it.

Comment: I updated the broken link on the other answer. You can add another answer to that question if you feel it would help. But the two questions are duplicates and there's no need to have two different places for answers.

Comment: @dc37 sure thing. I've corrected the wording in the question text.

Comment: @MrFlick, agreed. Thanks